# Default button without form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to trigger a default button when an user push Intro in the keyboard, but this Vue.js page doesn't have a form.  How should I proceed?

Comment: Where is your [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by intro? Im assuming you mean when the 'enter' key is pressed?
Try this code  [lesson](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp):

```html
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```